# c# File.Exists cannot find file

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

How to correctly define if file exist or not?

```
string FilePath = Path.Combine(dir, "www", "index.html");

if (!File.Exists(FilePath))
{
     // get here anyway
}

string dir
{
     get
     {
          string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
          UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
          string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
          return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
     }
}
```

`File.Exists` return `false` anyway, whether the file exists or not.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the path you're creating is correct? What value are you passing in for `dir`? Have you checked the value of `FilePath` with a breakpoint to make sure it matches your file location?

Comment: What is the value you are getting in `FilePath` variable? Can you share some values of it for which you think it should return true and false.

Comment: Technically you are calling the right function your issue could be two things.

Your software does not have access to that file path to check if the file exists or the path is incorrect.

Can you provide more details, are you in debug ? are you in a web application?

Comment: @DavidLebee I'm writting simple web server

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `FilePath`? What is the **exact** value of `dir`?

Answer (score 2):

First: check the result of your `Path.Combine()` call. You might not be getting what you expect there.

Second: File.Exists() only acts on the local file system. It sounds like that is what you meant here, but if you where expecting it to check on a remote web server, that won't work.

Third: There are a few reasons File.Exists() can return false even when the file exists. Make sure you read all the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx), but permission issues and malformed paths can also cause it to return false.

Fourth: The file system is **volatile**, meaning it's usually not a good idea to use File.Exists() in the first place. You do much better just trying to open the file, and handling the exception if it fails.

Comment: 1) `FilePath` contains correct path
2) I'm working with server's local file system
3) not sure about permissions
4) cannot read file into FileStream

Answer (score 0):

I suggest two things
1. **Path.Combine()** function have chance to mix both folder and file name are same, suppose if your folder name is index , then you have change get FALSE for more info look at [Combine function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)
2.Use get currect directory using **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory**